# Share a screenshot from Edge with Outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

The web note and screenshot sharing feature of Edge is really nice, but the out-of-the-box sharing options for me are only Mail and OneNote. I'd love to share via email **through Outlook**.

[image: sharing options in Edge]

Is there a way to add to this list of options?

Answer (score 0):

simply: no

I am sure to answer the question. There are not further details and I also spent a lot on this subject. There is currently no interface between in sharing between modern apps and desktops apps. you will also experience this with oneNoe App vs. Desktop